# How do I disable this confirm dialog and force sleep?

Tags: suspend, hibernate

Sometimes when I try to suspend my pc, I get this dialog from xfce4-power-manager: "Are you sure you want to hibernate the system? An application is currently disabling the automatic sleep. Doing this action now may damage the working state of this application." And I have to confirm that every time which I want to skip automaticly.